# adjusting the width of HTML WordPress Widget

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget

I am working on WordPress and I have the following code in a HTML widget in the footer, however the email is displaying on 2 different lines, how can I have the email display properly on 1 line, thanks! it shows as:

line 1:      office@glassche

line 2 underneath it:      m.eu

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <i class="ion-ios-location-outline"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
        <p>Plovdiv, Bulgaria</p>
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <i class="ion-ios-telephone-outline"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
        <p>
            <span>+359 32 680 129</span>
            <br/>
            <small>Mon-Fri, 8.30am until 
    5.00pm</small>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <i class="ion-ios-email-outline"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
        <p>
            <span>office@glasschem.eu</span>
            <br/>
            <small>We reply within 24 
    hours</small>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's not enough to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Do you have additionnal css? Are you on a computer or mobile screen?

Comment: @Firefly I think so, it's might be too small that it wrap underneath.

Comment: Have you read [Bootstrat Grid System Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is fine in html.
Its shows like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thhaC.png)

Maybe you remove the span tag, give it a class and apply css to it

**display:inline-block;**

It should work for you in WordPress widget.

Comment: He is using bootstrap two column class, so inline-block wont work here

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fit the email inside col-md-2 of width:16.33%, so it wont fit and it is breaking into two lines

use this css for email span tag

```
span{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```